# How to harvest and process walnuts?

Tags: harvesting, walnut

I came across a fallen [walnut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juglans_regia#/media/File:Juglans_regia_2009_G2.jpg) tree and harvested some. Vaguely remembering from my childhood that the husk is to be removed and the nut dried in the sun I proceeded only to realize I have no idea what am I doing.

The husk doesn't separate cleanly so the process degrades to peeling like an apple skin instead of "two slashes with the knife and then drop the husk".

And I don't even know where to begin with sun-drying. Is it required (the walnuts look more mature than on the picture but were still picked before falling to the ground)? Is the sun required or can it be done in the dark? When are they ready?

Comment: It depends on if the nuts were mature when the tree fell . Many kinds of nut drop from the tree when mature.

Comment: Seems very likely that the nuts are immature (Northern Hemisphere) or were when it died (Southern Hemisphere) since no location is given, and it's the wrong time of year for nuts to be ripe in the Northern Hemisphere where walnuts are willing to grow, in my experience. Presumably mid-winter in the Southern Hemisphere, long past when nuts should have fallen to the ground. In short, you probably have compost material, not harvestable nuts.